# Eclipse - Find/Replace to remove line without leaving blank space?

Tags: eclipse, replace, ide

I'm trying to globally remove a line from numerous files in my Eclipse Java project.  It's easy to use Eclipse's search/replace functionality to do so.  However, when I do that I'm left with a blank, empty line where the replaced text used to be.  For example, if I had something like this:

```
   /**
   * 
   * 
  **/
  @javax.annotation.Nullable
  public void someMethod() {
    ...
  }
```

And I ran a search/replace to replace `@javax.annotation.Nullable` with *nothing*, I'd end up with:

```
   /**
   * 
   * 
  **/

  public void someMethod() {
    ...
  }
```

I don't want the blank space before my method declaration.  Is there a way to do a search/replace to remove the unwanted string AND prevent it from leaving a blank line/space?

Comment: Try if you can match the trailing newline using `\R` or `\r?\n` enabling regex https://regex101.com/r/aj4Mqv/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird that did it!  Thanks!